# select forms based on user selected

Tags: java

There can be 20 vehicles max for a user.I Have 5 static forms.Based on the user selection i want to merge the pdfs

*1.pdf - 1 veh,2.pdf - 2 veh,3.pdf - 3 veh, 4.pdf - 4 veh, 5.df  - 5 veh*

if user have more than 5 vehicles like 6 veh then each form should accomodate  5.pdf+1.pdf not other combination like 3+3 or 2+3+1 etc.
20 vehicles 5+5+5+5,13 veh 5+5+3,7 veh  5+2,18 veh 5+5+5+3,3 veh 3. Could any one help me out in having a logic to pick which forms user should select to merge instead of writing 20 if loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that a bundle of forms will either be a single form 1-5, or else some number of 5-forms and a single form 1-5. There will be no other combinations. It's basically like you're counting forms in base-5.

First, take care of as many 5.pdf forms as needed. If the number of forms is greater than 5, you'll want to add at least 1 5.pdf files. If the number of forms is greater than 10, you'll want to add at least 2 5.pdf files. You can do that, among other ways, by continuously adding 5.pdf forms until your count is less than 5.

In pseudocode, you could do the following:

```
List forms = new ArrayList();
int count = <number of vehicles>

while count > 0 {
   if ( count >= 5 ) {
      forms.add( "5.pdf" );
      count = count - 5;
   } else {
      forms.add( "" + count + ".pdf" );
      count = 0;
   }
}

<forms now contains the list of all forms you need>
```

Or if you want, you could simplify it as follows:

```
int numberOfFives = (formsCount / 5); // Integer division, so if formsCount = 4, numberOfFives = 0
int remainingForm = (formsCount % 5); // Remainder after division by 5
```

And then you'd add `numberOfFives` 5.pdf forms and a single `remainingForm`.pdf form to your concatenated PDF.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the pdf names are not 1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf,4.pdf,5.pdf.they are like a.pdf,b.pdf,c.pdf,d.pdf,e.pdf

Comment: if pdf names are different as i mentoioned above. Please let me know.

Comment: You'd want to just have a mapping from the number to the name of the PDF then. This could be done any number of ways, from a java.util.Map to an XML file, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to repeatedly subtract the largest value that is less than our equal to the target. For example:

```
8: greatest is 5, 8-5=3
3: greatest is 3, 3-3=0, we're finished
8=5+3
```